# Extracting the query from the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How to get the parameter value from the URL using Javascript or Jquery whatever is more easy!

I get this URL

```
 http://website.in/instant/#mystring
```

And I want

```
 mystring
```

Only the string after the # from the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.location.hash` returns the hash with "#", so you could use: `window.location.hash.substr(1)`

Comment: `window.location.hash.replace('#','')` is safer because some older browsers (IE<=6 I think) return the hash-string without the leading #.

Answer (score 3):

You want [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Comment: I know that ! But how do I extract the exact string from the query?

Comment: @NarendraRajput : i see you have answers eveywhere. just do "window.location.hash" wherever you need the data.